# Geocoding with Stata mqtime and travletime command

Tags: geocoding, stata

I try to calc distances with the mqtime and traveltime command but it does not work. I already extracted the lat and long of my observations but now it does not work to calc the distances those a the commands:

```
mqtime, start_x(origin_long_1) start_y(origin_lat_1) end_x(destination_long_1) end_y(destination_lat_1)
```

> error: type mismatch after 30 var but it also did not calc for the first 30

```
traveltime, start_x(origin_lat_1) start_y(origin_long_1) end_x(destination_lat_1) end_y(destination_long_1)
```

> error: file http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&output=dragdir&saddr=9.180046,48.77849&daddr=9.180046,48.77849&dirflg= not found

how can I solve the problem?

Comment: It's very difficult to comment unless you show us the data input. Check out the requirements for a minimal reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please amend the question. Note that by data input, I really do mean the data, not a description of the data. No one can reproduce your problem from what you have told us so far.

Comment: how can I provide the data input best?

Comment: By following the advice in the link cited above.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments in a [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984789/geocoding-with-stata), you have lat/lon coordinates and you are trying to calculate distances between those points. Using the data you provided in the comments, here's an example of how to use `geodist` (from SSC) to calculate the distances.

```
clear
input str10 pub_nbr double( origin_lat  origin_long destination_lat destination_long)
EP0020938   48.778493 9.180046  48.778493   9.180046 
EP0104636   48.778493   9.180046    35.257529   139.681465 
EP0140295 48.778493 9.180046    35.6759796  139.763504 
EP0142993   48.778493   9.180046    35.124905   136.936815 
EP0144057   48.778493   9.180046    35.6759796  139.763504 
EP0148622   48.778493   9.180046    35.124905 136.936815 
EP0152942   48.778493   9.180046    35.455592   139.572196
end

geodist origin_lat  origin_long destination_lat destination_long, gen(d)
```

Note that if you are trying to calculate the distances between all points, then you should take a look at `geonear` (also from SSC).

Comment: To follow-up on why `mqtime` "did not work" for the OP,  he should no be surprised if the travel distance by car from Schlossplatz, Stuttgart to points in Japan are missing. The type mismatch error is due to bad programming in `mqtime` ( `if _rc !="0" {`). I would say that `mqtime` is not ready for prime time as there are other serious problems with the code (e.g. variable name conflicts).

Answer (score 0):

The problem cannot be solved using `traveltime` or `mqtime`: The command `traveltime` is outdated since Google's new API. The follow-up command `traveltime3`, which was build to work with the new API, is, unfortunately, not available anymore for reasons of Google's Terms of Use. The command `mqtime` does not work anymore, too, since Mapquest completely restructured their API licensing. 
The user-written Stata command `osrmtime`, which is based on open source software, can solve the problem.